# Access sharepoint Directory using path in graph api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

As I have tried to fetch the data of a directory using the path in the the graph api as shown below

## **[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{directory](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drive/root:/%7Bdirectory) or file path}**

and got the following error :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7XC4.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following api

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root:/{item-path}
```

Comment: but the above method is also possible right ?